# Bridge for collision domains

Tags: switch, layer2, bridge, layer1

I have read that a bridge/switch can be used to increase the number of collision domains in the network, but somewhere I also read that a bridge reduces collision domains. Is it possible for bridge to reduce a collision domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bridge (a switch is a high-density bridge) can help reduce the number of devices in a collision domain by breaking a single collision domain into multiple, separate collision domains with fewer devices on each collision domain than were on the original collision domain.

Each interface on a bridge is a separate collision domain. Assuming you were replacing a hub, where every interface is in the same collision domain, with a switch. Suddenly, you have more collision domains, but there are less devices on each collision domain than were on the original collision domain.

Comment: So then i can say that bridge dont reduce collision domain,it increases collision domains.however number of devices in each collision domain reduces as compared to original collision domain where  hub was used?

Comment: It reduces the size of a collision domain (this is what is important) by increasing the number of collision domains. Overall, this reduces the number of collisions, which helps increase throughput.