# Why collision domain occurs in hubs but not switches

Tags: switch, ethernet, layer2, lan

**if anyone knows the actual point and in depth answer to my question please help. the links in the comments didn't helped at all**

Most of the websites which i saw are just vaguely saying that collision domain occurs in hub and not in switches. But how exactly is that?
My question is:
Hubs and switches are both used in LAN and can be connected via twisted pair cables which can be half or full duplex.
Does hubs and switches both uses CSMA with CD?

```
COMPUTERS A,B,C,D
A->B: a is trying to send the data
Assuming CMSA/CD is used. I'm not sure if it is used
```

Hubs use twisted pair. Means they have separate pair for sending and receiving data.

**case 1**:
suppose if they use Twisted Pair(TP) in half duplex mode(means either sending or receiving is allowed at an instance), while one device is sending the data A->B,C,D, device B->A,C,D cannot able to send because device B should carrier sense and not send the data until TP becomes idle. So device B waits for random interval of time. so how collision occurs?

**case 2**:
If they operate in Full duplex mode(can send and receive at same time via different pairs), if one device A -> B,C,D receiving the data. At the same time if device B wants to send the data, it can send using sending pair of TP as it is free, and once the data receives hub, it carrier senses that devices C,D receiving pair are not idle and waits for some random interval of time before sending the data again.
If hub uses full duplex with CSMA/CD how exactly collision occurs?

**case 3**

In case of switches, A->B and C->B at the same time doesn't collision occurs? If No, then why?

**Please don't explain vaguely be specific. I hope you understand**

Comment: There are a lot of questions with answer here that explain it. For example: [this one](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/58917/8499), [this one](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/43321/8499), [this one](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/52146/8499), etc.

Comment: @RonMaupin have you read my question completely? The post which you have shared not even answer a little bit of my problem

Comment: @RonMaupin is there is no collision at all in switches or there is a reduced collision?

Comment: Yes I read your question completely, but is seems you did not read the answers completely. For example, the part where it is explained that a hub is basically just a powered cable, but switches have intelligence to switch frames?

Comment: i don't get it how hubs cause collision domain

Comment: Hubs are like a cable. If all hosts are connected to the same cable, multiple hosts transmitting simultaneously will cause a collision because the signals interfere, crating a garbage signal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133634/discussion-between-vinter-and-ron-maupin).

Comment: "_If hub uses full duplex with CSMA/CD how exactly collision occurs?_" Hubs cannot use full duplex. A shared medium such as wired ethernet on a hub, or wireless, such as Wi-Fi, is inherently half duplex. "_If hub uses half duplex A->B,C,D, if B->A,C,D then B carrier senses that A is sending data so it waits for random interval till the cable gets idle and should send data. how exactly collision occurs here?_" A device can start sending after another host is sending because the signal has not yet reached the second host, then you have a collision.

Comment: @RonMaupin got it for half duplex. But why wired ethernet is inherently half duplex? I can use twisted pair which has different pair for sending and receiving data. Which solves collision domain isn't it?

Comment: most of the people uses twisted pair in full duplex mode isn't it?

Comment: "_I can use twisted pair which has different pair for sending and receiving data._" Not on a hub. The transmit pair of a host is connected to the receive pairs of all the other hosts, so two hosts sending will collide on all the receive pairs. All this is described in answers already posted here if you would only search. Your questions are duplicates, and hubs are extinct, so they are off-topic as historical trivia.

Comment: If you look carefully you'll see that a collision does not happen *in* a hub, but *on a port* that is using half-duplex mode / CSMA/CD. That happens with a hub (always) and a switch (only for HDX ports) alike. The hub propagates the collision while the switch does not.